# How do I remove all roles from a user?

Tags: permissions, discord.js

I am trying to make a suspended command and the only way to have the role work is to have all other roles to be removed from the user. When I execute the command in discord it spits this out into the console saying that it doesn't have permissions when both the bot and user have them:

```
> C:\Users\dubwi\Desktop\LDU_Bot>node .
Ready
(node:16868) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
{ DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at item.request.gen.end (C:\Users\dubwi\Desktop\LDU_Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:79:15)
    at then (C:\Users\dubwi\Desktop\LDU_Bot\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  name: 'DiscordAPIError',
  message: 'Missing Permissions',
  path:
   '/api/v7/guilds/418505146876559371/members/311651448519786496',
  code: 50013,
  method: 'PATCH' }
```

```js
case "suspend":
  if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) {
    let rMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0])); //Gets the user
    if (!rMember) return message.reply("That user does not exist.");
    let gRole = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'SUSPENDED'); //Gets the SUSPENDED role

    rMember.removeRoles(rMember.roles).then(console.log).catch(console.error); //Removes all roles
    rMember.addRole(gRole.id); //Adds suspended Role


    message.channel.send("User was suspended."); //Messages the channel that the user was suspended

    try {
      await rMember.send("You have been suspended."); //Tries to DM User
    } catch (e) {
      message.channel.send("We tried to DM the user to let them know, but their DM's are locked."); //Announces that their DMs are locked
    }


  } else {
    message.channel.send("You do not have permission to use this command.");
  }
  break;
```

Comment: Like error said, missing permission. Make sure bot has 'manage roles' permission and it's role is higher than user's role in roles list

Comment: That was it. The bot's role was under the users i was testing on.

Comment: Could you put the solution in an answer and then accept it? In this way the question is marked as solved properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error code said, you're missing permissions;

> DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

This means that the bot is missing the permissions it needs in order to execute the `removeRoles()` function.